# Mapping numeric values to string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, machine-learning

Here I have a dataset:

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1drS.png)

I want to map numeric value to `CASE_STATUS` values

```
df.CASE_STATUS.value_counts()

CERTIFIED              2615623
CERTIFIED-WITHDRAWN     202659
DENIED                   94346
```

Here is what I do but have a `string indices must be integers, not str` error:

```
for dataset in df:
    dataset['CASE_STATUS'] = dataset['CASE_STATUS'].map( {'CERTIFIED':1 , 'CERTIFIED-WITHDRAWN': 1, 'DENIED': 0} ).astype(int)
```

How should I map values to `CASE_STATUS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a `for` loop for this:

```
dict_map = {'CERTIFIED':1 , 'CERTIFIED-WITHDRAWN': 1, 'DENIED': 0}

df['CASE_STATUS'] = df['CASE_STATUS'].map(dict_map).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a mapping you can use the pandas method `to_dict`.

For example :

```
mapping = df.reset_index().CASE_STATUS.to_dict()
```

Note that I use `reset_index()` before to be sure that index go from 0 to n (n = number of row you have).

Then you can convert your column with a simple map :

```
df["CASE_STATUS"] = df["CASE_STATUS"].map(mapping)
```

It is interesting to keep a track of your mapping transformation, that's why the dictionnary creation is an important step.